# Low Level Mouse Hook вызывает проблемы с производительностью

Tags: c#, wpf, hook

Хочу получать текущие координаты курсора по мере изменения его положения. На данный момент реализовал (по примерам из интернета следующее):

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    private static LowLevelMouseProc mouseProcess = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr hookId = IntPtr.Zero;
    private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

    private delegate void MouseMoveHandler(Point point);
    private static event MouseMoveHandler MousePositionChanged;

    private enum MouseMessages
    {
        WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
        WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
        WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
        WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
        WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
        WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205
    }


    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelMouseProc proc)
    {
        using (Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule currentModule = currentProcess.MainModule)
        {                
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc,
                GetModuleHandle(currentModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && MouseMessages.WM_MOUSEMOVE == (MouseMessages)wParam)
        {
            var hookStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));

            MousePositionChanged?.Invoke(new Point(hookStruct.pt.x, hookStruct.pt.y));

            UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookId);
            
            hookId = SetHook(mouseProcess);
        }

        return CallNextHookEx(hookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct POINT
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
    {
        public POINT pt;
        public uint mouseData;
        public uint flags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }


    #region DllImport
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
        LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
        IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
    #endregion
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
  public MainWindow()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      DataContext = this;
      Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();

      CreateMouseHook();            
  }

  private void CreateMouseHook()
  {
      mouseProcess = HookCallback;
      hookId = SetHook(mouseProcess);
  }
```

Проблема заключается в том, что код выше подтормаживает сами передвижения курсора (вне зависимости от окна, на котором он находится) и рано или поздно выбрасывает OutOfMemoryException. Обработчик MousePositionChanged не влияет, пробовал запускать с пустым - всё та же проблема. Буду благодарен любой помощи. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `HookCallback` - зачем перехукивать хук в хукоколбэке, при чем при каждом его вызове, когда он уже хукнутый изначально? Уберите последние 2 строчки из колбэка. А `UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookId);` вынесите в обработчик `Window_Closing`.

Comment: @aepot, спасибо! Всё работает как должно, странно, что до самого не дошло.

Comment: `OutOfMemoryException` скорее всего происходит потому что вы не высвобождаете где-то неуправляемую память. Если после того, как вы убрали перехукивание проблема сохранилась, надо искать, где течёт.

Comment: @aepot, нет, всё в порядке. Проблема была в том, о чем Вы и сказали.